# Importing file into r, error "no trailing characters"

Tags: r, import

I'm very new to R, so this might make no sense. I've tried to find a pre-existing question that answers this, but I don't seem to understand any of the ones that exist.

Here's what I'm inputing:

```
#Loading data
library(tidyverse)
scdbv_mod <- read_csv("data/SCDB_2016_01_justiceCentered_Citation.csv")
```

And here's what happens:

> ```
> Warning: 50165 parsing failures.
>  row    col               expected actual
> 1225 docket no trailing characters      M
> 1226 docket no trailing characters      M
> 1227 docket no trailing characters      M
> 1228 docket no trailing characters      M
> 1229 docket no trailing characters      M
> ```

I've tried to parse the docket column, but it's not exactly working and I'm somewhat stuck. I'm sure I"m missing something pretty obvious.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: See [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Can you show us the first lines of the CSV file?

Comment: Have you tried `?read_csv` or `?read.csv`.

Comment: You say "I've tried to parse the docket column" - can you show us your code for that?

Comment: I posted the answer yesterday and never heard back from you @Rita. Did you see it? I've deleted it now. Is the problem solved?

Comment: Likely relevant: https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/645